# Recommended EC2 AMI for high traffic PHP web service

Tags: amazon-ec2, nginx

I hope I'm asking this question in the right place.

I have a web service serving widgets  with about 500K hits /day. Traffic is expected to double monthly.

It is currenty on VPS with Plesk 8 /Centos 5 / Apache 2/ Php 5.2.6 /Mysql 5.0.45 / Memcached / APC

I'm seeing occasional kmemsize errors and also tcpbuff errors.

To solve this I decided to use Nginx as reverse proxy. Adding Nginx to Plesk systems seems to be problematic, therefore I'm now checking the possiblity of using EC2 instead.

What AMI is recommended for my setting (high traffic PHP web service?) It needs to support millions of requests a day. I need an OS that can be easily maintained by non expert + NGinx and my entire configuration + Security and other essential management features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used scalr.com.

Answer (score 2):

A single AMI is probably not going to address all of your needs.

For starters,  I would recommend using CloudFront + ESI to handle your widgets.  Amazon AWS also supports an automated load balancer that can address a lot of your performance issues.

You could also use S3 to handle some of the static assets.

The bottom line is that you could create a  Plesk 8 /Centos 5 / Apache 2/ Php 5.2.6 /Mysql 5.0.45 / Memcached / APC AMI and run as many of them as you want.  If you are getting kmemsize errors you likely have just maxed out your current VPS and need to get a bigger one.